# Remove empty Space between Paragrahps

Tags: html, css

There are 3 paragraphs in below snippet.

if you run the below snippet, you can see more space between 2 paragraphs. i want to reduce those space.

if i remove `<br/>` tag than no space will display, but i want to keep little space.

```html
<p>sitename brings you the stylish and trendy <b>God Created the Earth Apple Iphone 5s Phone case</b> made up with top quality Plycarbonae hard case. With all sitename mobile back cover for your <b>Apple Iphone 5s</b>, you can ensure optimum protection for your <b>Iphone 5s</b> from scratches and drop protection keeping all the awesome design to showoff to the world. We never compromise with the quality of design or with our phone cases so you always receive best phone cover for your beautiful <b>Apple Iphone 5s.</b></p>
<br/>
<p>We have many more cool, latest and trendy designs available for your <b>Apple iphone 5s</b> device. You can explore all our best designer <b><a href="http://sitename.com/cases-covers/apple-iphone-5s.html"><span style="color:#0000FF;">Apple Iphone 5s Phone Case and Cover here</a></b></p>
<br/>
<ul>
<li>All Style Baby&rsquo;s <b>Apple iphone 5s</b> Cases and Covers tested for quality before we dispatch from here.</li>
<li>sitename Mobile Covers are highly protective, fashionable and trendy.</li>
<li><b>God Created the Earth Apple Iphone 5s Phone case</b> fits perfectly to your Apple iphone 5s.</li>
<li>sitename <b>Apple iphone 5s</b> Phone Covers are made from Poly Carbonate and are strong and durable.</li>
<li>This Apple iphone 5s Mobile Back cover designs Cases are less bulky and lightweight.</li>
</ul>
<p>Don&rsquo;t like this Design? Explore all other designs for your <b><a href="http://sitename.com/cases-covers/apple-iphone-5s.html"><span style="color:#0000FF;">designs for your Apple Iphone 5s here<span></a></b></p>
```

Comment: removing the `<br>` does show some space for me.

Comment: if it's in 2 paragraphs you will have a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the default margin and padding for `p` tag

```css
p { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

```html
<p>We brings you the stylish and trendy <b>God Created the Earth Apple Iphone 5s Phone case</b> made up with top quality Plycarbonae hard case. With all we mobile back cover for your <b>Apple Iphone 5s</b>, you can ensure optimum protection for your <b>Iphone 5s</b> from scratches and drop protection keeping all the awesome design to showoff to the world. We never compromise with the quality of design or with our phone cases so you always receive best phone cover for your beautiful <b>Apple Iphone 5s.</b></p>
<br/>
<p>We have many more cool, latest and trendy designs available for your <b>Apple iphone 5s</b> device. You can explore all our best designer <b><a href="http://we.com/cases-covers/apple-iphone-5s.html"><span style="color:#0000FF;">Apple Iphone 5s Phone Case and Cover here</a></b></p>
<br/>
<ul>
<li>All we &rsquo;s <b>Apple iphone 5s</b> Cases and Covers tested for quality before we dispatch from here.</li>
<li>we Mobile Covers are highly protective, fashionable and trendy.</li>
<li><b>God Created the Earth Apple Iphone 5s Phone case</b> fits perfectly to your Apple iphone 5s.</li>
<li>we<b>Apple iphone 5s</b> Phone Covers are made from Poly Carbonate and are strong and durable.</li>
<li>This Apple iphone 5s Mobile Back cover designs Cases are less bulky and lightweight.</li>
</ul>
<p>Don&rsquo;t like this Design? Explore all other designs for your <b><a href="http://we.com/cases-covers/apple-iphone-5s.html"><span style="color:#0000FF;">designs for your Apple Iphone 5s here<span></a></b></p>
```

Comment: add this to your p tag p {     margin: 0px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 20px; }

Comment: Do not use break as we are giving margin-bottom:10px after paragraph

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121242/discussion-between-shahil-and-css-beginner).

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: please help me for [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561910/menu-dropdown-not-displaying-menu-items-in-internet-explorer/)

Comment: It might be an issue with z-index of the submenu

Comment: i tried with `.ms-submenu {
   z-index: 1000000;
}` still didt worked for me.....

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`<P>`  elements by default have some margin.
Add  css `margin: 5px 0px;` to it.
Increase/decrease it to how much you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `</br>` from your code. Paragraph has default margin `bottom` and `top`

**OR**

Remove default margin from `paragraph` and keep `</br>`

(First method is better as you don't need to add a new css to overwrite some styles)

```html
<p>Stylename brings you the stylish and trendy <b>God Created the Earth Apple Iphone 5s Phone case</b> made up with top quality Plycarbonae hard case. With all sitename mobile back cover for your <b>Apple Iphone 5s</b>, you can ensure optimum protection for your <b>Iphone 5s</b> from scratches and drop protection keeping all the awesome design to showoff to the world. We never compromise with the quality of design or with our phone cases so you always receive best phone cover for your beautiful <b>Apple Iphone 5s.</b></p>

<p>We have many more cool, latest and trendy designs available for your <b>Apple iphone 5s</b> device. You can explore all our best designer <b><a href="http://sitename.com/cases-covers/apple-iphone-5s.html"><span style="color:#0000FF;">Apple Iphone 5s Phone Case and Cover here</a></b></p>

<ul>
<li>All sitename&rsquo;s <b>Apple iphone 5s</b> Cases and Covers tested for quality before we dispatch from here.</li>
<li>sitename Mobile Covers are highly protective, fashionable and trendy.</li>
<li><b>God Created the Earth Apple Iphone 5s Phone case</b> fits perfectly to your Apple iphone 5s.</li>
<li>sitename <b>Apple iphone 5s</b> Phone Covers are made from Poly Carbonate and are strong and durable.</li>
<li>This Apple iphone 5s Mobile Back cover designs Cases are less bulky and lightweight.</li>
</ul>
<p>Don&rsquo;t like this Design? Explore all other designs for your <b><a href="http://sitename.com/cases-covers/apple-iphone-5s.html"><span style="color:#0000FF;">designs for your Apple Iphone 5s here<span></a></b></p>
```

Comment: Haha actually I was copied your snippet.

Comment: I'm not getting you.

Comment: @cssbeginner Done that bro. I already edited that to stylename